# SImple php form hanling code is not working

Tags: php, html, forms

The code is showing undefined index for name and email , I have checked thoroughly for the correct name, still can't figure it out

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$name1 = $_POST["name"];
echo $name1;
 echo "true";

 ?>
   Welcome <?php echo $name1 ?><br>
     Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

    </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: What does `die(print_r($_POST, true));` outputs?

Comment: Try `isset()` for checking the `$_POST[]`

Answer (score 1):

Post values will be get after form submit or values post. initially it will be null so you need to apply some check to avoid warnings using `isset()` or `empty()`

```
$name1 = (!empty($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : '');
```

try same for `$_POST["email"]`

Answer (score 1):

Add this on the top of your document:-

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

And declare your variables.

Or use isset() to check if they are declared before referencing them, as in: $value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';.